# How to replace content of a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i have a bunch of HTML files that i would like to fix the markup on with the help of bs4. But once i run the code, all files are just empty (lucky my i made a backup before running my script on the folder).

This is what i have so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
for entry in os.scandir(path):
    if entry.is_file() and entry.path.endswith('html'):
        file = open(entry.path, 'w+')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'html.parser')
        file.write(soup.prettify())
        print(colored('Success', 'green'))
        file.close()
```

The expected result would be that the file is read, prettyfied and saved.

Comment: no errors? can you show the contents oh the file

Comment: No errors, just "success" and blank files :D

Comment: Try printing the output of `soup` or `soup.prettify()` before saving it maybe it isn't loading/parsing correctly and just outputting `None`?

Comment: @Jab, i have done that. seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

opening the file with "W +" you delete what's in it before you can read.
Solution:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
for entry in os.scandir(path):
    if entry.is_file() and entry.path.endswith('html'):
        readFile = open(entry.path, 'r')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(readFile, 'html.parser')
        readFile.close()
        writeFile = open(entry.path, 'w')
        writeFile.write(soup.prettify())
        writeFile.close()
        print(colored('Success', 'green'))
```

Answer (score 0):

you have truncated the files with the access modifier of `+w`. Take a look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/python-open-built-in-function-difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r/30566011#30566011) which explains in detail which mode you require.

More information from the python docs can be found [here for 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) and for [python3](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: Alright but i want to truncate the file, and then save it with new content (prettyfied)

Comment: then you require to read the file contents first so in `r` only mode and then create another new file `w` mode to dump the new contents

Answer (score 0):

You've used the 'w+' mode to open the file.
This clears/ truncates all file content.

Use 'r' to read file contents, then process them, and use 'w+' to overwrite the file with the processed contents.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
for entry in os.scandir(path):
    if entry.is_file() and entry.path.endswith('html'):
        with open(entry.path, 'r') as f:
            readfile = f.read()
        readFile = open(entry.path, 'r')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(readFile, 'html.parser')
        with open(entry.path, 'w+') as f:
            readfile = f.write(soup.prettify())
        print(colored('Success', 'green'))
```

For more info about modes of opening files in python see these resources:

[Excellent StackOverflow answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/python-open-built-in-function-difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r/30566011#30566011)

[Manpagez](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fopen/)

[Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)